# Reading from & writing to user-specific page

Tags: php

I'm new to web development and php, but i'm knowledgeable in Java, Python, C and programming in general.

I want to create a user-specific page that stores the IP addresses of the user (and users have access to view his own page that contains his ip addresses).

A program will access my website through a specific url:

```
<mydomainname>.com/index.php?option=com_auth&username=<insertusername>&password=<insertpassword>
```

And the php script for com_auth extension will authenticate the credentials through

```
if ($response->status != JAuthentication::STATUS_SUCCESS) {
```

following which it will grab the ip address of the user by

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Now i need to append this address to an user specific page.

How do i create such a page in joomla, and how can the php read & write to the page?

Answer (score 1):

I might have misunderstood your question, so please feel free to elaborate/correct me if I misunderstood.

You will need to create a table, let's call it `#__users_ip` that contains 3 fields: `userid` which is the user id of the user that has logged in, `ip` which is the IP of the user, and `login_datetime` which is the `datetime` when the user logged in. (`#__` is your table prefix [for some reason, Joomla calls it `$dbprefix` in the `configuration.php` file, which is short for database prefix, which I personally think it's wrong])

Every time a person logs in, you insert his user and his IP to that table. Then, in the extension of your choice (I don't know how you want to retrieve the data), you can just pass the user id and get the IPs he logged in from and at what time. Hope that helps!